# How can I validate that consecutive numbers in a string aren't sequential?

Tags: ruby, string, validation, passwords, integer

I've been tasked with a very simple password verification scheme, but for the life of me, I cannot seem to get this right. Here is the task:

> The user sends a numeric password of 6 characters through a form. In
>   order to force secure passwords create a validation that the numbers
>   cannot consecutively go up or down.

Here is what I have:

```
password = '246879'
new_password = password.split('').map { |s| s.to_i }

new_password.each_with_index do |val, index|

  next_element = new_password[index + 1]
  prev_element = new_password[index - 1]

  if new_password[index] + 1 == next_element
    puts 'next bad'
    break
  elsif
    new_password[index] - 1 == prev_element
    puts 'prev bad'
    break
  end
end
```

The password should fail on the 87 because 7 is one less than 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like CodeGnome's answer but I'd simplify it a bit.

```
def valid_password?(password)
  password.chars.each_cons(2).none? do |a, b|
    (a.ord - b.ord).abs == 1
  end
end

p valid_password?('246879')
#=> false

p valid_password?('246809')
#=> true
```

This assumes that all of the characters are digits (i.e. some other code validates this). Since `"0"` through `"9"` are in order in UTF-8 (as in ASCII), we don't need to convert them to numbers, we just need to compare their character codes. It also uses [`Enumerable#none?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F) since this sort of problem is exactly what it's there for.

Comment: Your answer is definitely more compact than mine, so +1. I try to avoid clever code in favor of explicitness, but I really like that this answer returns the value of the expression itself rather than relying on branching to return a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to compare a sliding window of characters or integers. For example:

```
def valid_password? str_of_ints
  str_of_ints.chars.map(&:to_i).each_cons(2) do |i, j|
    return false if i.succ == j or i.pred == j
  end
  true
end

valid_password? '246879'
#=> false

valid_password? '246809'
#=> true
```